# python regex: match any style line break

Tags: python, regex

Is there a way to match a line break independently of system?  i.e. match both `\n` and `\r\n`.  The only thing I can think of is `\r?\n` which just feels clunky.

The reason I want to do this is

1. if I need to match 2 in a row, `\n\n` no longer works and
2. if I match `\n`, then the preceding `\r` will still exist and I would have to strip it off or it could lead to problems later

Comment: Do you need a regular expression or would reading a file line by line (with universal readlines) suffice?

Comment: @JeanHominal the point is to come up with something I can use in a larger regex.

Answer (score 4):

Wouldn't this get all groups of adjacent `\r` and `\n` characters regardless of order or amount?

**Edited per comments:**

`[\r\n]+`

Comment: `[\r\n]*` will match an empty string and empty strings before any non-matching texts.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that can be fixed with `+`: `[\r\n]+`

Answer (score 3):

This should be good for cross-platform line break

```
regex = '(\r\n?|\n)+'
```

Comment: are you sure of the `r` prefix in that case?

Comment: Yes, r makes sure the raw text

Comment: Yes, works (although works without too)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre updated comment :D